# Limiting sequence in two ways.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For $\sqrt{(n + 1)} - \sqrt{n}$, sequence I am testing convergence and limits.
Indeed it seems converging. Then,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{(n + 1)} - \sqrt{n} = 0 $$
But if telescopic series taken,
 $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N\left[\sqrt{(n + 1)} - \sqrt{n}\right]$$
  $$i.e. \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{N-1+1}-\sqrt{N-1}+\sqrt{N+1}-\sqrt{N} $$

sums left with  $$\lim_{N\to \infty} [-\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{N-1} + \sqrt{N+1} ] = -1$$.
I have tried so far this. Is this will be a good way to deal with sequence?

Comment: `But if telescopic series taken` Series of *what*? The previous $\lim$ referred to some sequence $\sqrt{(n + 1)} - \sqrt{n}$ which does indeed converge to $0$. Where does the series come into the picture, or otherwise put, what is your question?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your calculation. The term $-\sqrt(N-1)$ should be cancelled out.

Comment: @dxiv I am looking for infinite sum of sequence from two ways. But not sure about can go this way or not. Thanks.

Comment: @Jerry, yup its mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the telescoping sum you wrote, $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N\left[\sqrt{(n + 1)} - \sqrt{n}\right]$$

We can rearrange the terms so that we have the sum $$\lim_{N\to \infty}(-\sqrt1 - \sqrt2 - ... -\sqrt{N} + \sqrt2 + \sqrt3 +...+\sqrt{N} + \sqrt{N+1})$$

Once we cancel like terms, we have $\lim_{N \to \infty} (\sqrt{N+1} - \sqrt{1}) = \lim_{N \to \infty} (\sqrt{N+1} - 1) = \infty$

What this tells us is, even though the difference between two consecutive terms eventually reaches $0$, the sum of the consecutive differences need not converge.

Comment: Thanks :) for explaining. I am understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
$$