# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$ diverges.

I know that this diverges but I don't know how to prove it rigorously. Should I use the comparison theorem? I know that $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}>-\sqrt{k}$ so I just need to show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty -\sqrt{k}$ diverges. But that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Try writing out the first few terms. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: It is a telescoping sum and you know what the partial sums are. By definition, a series converges/diverges iff its partial sums converges/diverges.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191861/limiting-sequence-in-two-ways)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  For each positive integer $N$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^N (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}) = \sqrt{N+1}-\sqrt{1}.$$

Why is this so, and can you finish from here.

Comment: Is it that the limit of that goes to infinity as N goes to infinity? How did you find that $\sqrt{N+1}-\sqrt{1}$?